# How to update a PO Receipt line's PO number via API

Tags: acumatica

When I call the Acumatica REST API to update a PO Receipt, the PO Number field on the detail line is not updating. I'm just doing a PUT to the Default/17.200.001 endpoint, including a detail line. The PUT is successful, but the response returns an empty PONbr and POType on the detail line, and those fields are not updated. Are these fields read-only for some reason? How can I resolve this or override it so that these PO fields will update?

**Update #1 3/22:**
Per the response below, I tried putting these values in the insert instead of the update, but now I get a different error: "PO Error: Quantity must be greater than 0", and "PurchaseReceipt.Details[0].ReceiptQty: Quantity must be greater than 0". However, the ReceiptQty is there and is greater than 0.

**Update #2 3/22:**
You should be able to duplicate it with very simple steps:

1. Create a PO with Vendor, which defaults Location.
2. Add a PO Line with InventoryID, which defaults the line type and Warehouse
3. Enter the Order Qty
4. Save PO
5. In Postman, PUT similar JSON to what I supplied below for a PO Receipt, specifying a detail line with the referenced Inventory ID, PO Order Nbr, PO Order Type, Line Nbr, PO Line Nbr, Receipt Qty, Warehouse
6. The response is an error “PO Error: Quantity must be greater than 0”, “PurchaseReceipt.Details[0].ReceiptQty: Quantity must be greater than 0”

Here is sample json for the insert:

```
{
    "Date": {
        "value": "2019-03-22T00:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "Details": [
        {
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "0010006"
            },
            "LineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "Location": {
                "value": "01P"
            },
            "POLineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "POOrderNbr": {
                "value": "005554"
            },
            "POOrderType": {
                "value": "RO"
            },
            "ReceiptQty": {
                "value": 5
            },
            "Warehouse": {
                "value": "002"
            }
        }
    ],
    "PostPeriod": {
        "value": "032019"
    },
    "VendorID": {
        "value": "CVS TRADE"
    }
}
```

**Update #3 3/24:**
To try to get around Acumatica forcing ReceiptQty to 0, I tried adding a POReceiptLine_ReceiptQty_CacheAttached handler, without the PXDBQuantity, PXDefault, and PXFormula attributes to try to prevent it from getting zeroed out. That gives me a SQL error: "Incorrect syntax near 'INTranInTransit_INTransitLineStatus'" - whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

The logic there is that when you insert a Purchase Receipt detail line, if you specify the information about the Purchase order then the line will be added with a reference to original Purchase Order in the form of the PONbr and POType.

After the line is inserted the behavior through the web services is the same as the one on the screen, the PONbr and POType are read only field and cannot be modified.

During the insertion the parameter that are required to insert the Purchase Order Line properly are the PONbr, the POType and the POLineNbr.

**Update**

In certain case due to the complexity of an operation a special adapter was created in order to cover a specific scenario.
In this case the adding of a detail line to a purchase receipt is one of these scenarios. 
So only some specific values are required and the rest will be taken from the record in the system.

I think in your case that since the Purchase Order Line is/are already present on another Purchase Receipt, they have a Open quantity of 0 which is then put as the value for the Receipt quantity. Unfortunately this then trigger an error since the receipt quantity in a purchase receipt cannot be 0.

Comment: I am supplying all three fields you mention to the PUT, and they are not updating.  Or are you saying that they have to be on the PUT insert and not the update?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean you need to specify these field during the insert

Comment: If you go to the screen and Insert a line,you will notice you cannot update these field once the line exist.

Comment: I added these fields to the insert, but now it's complaining about quantity must be greater than zero for ReceiptQty.  However, it is greater than zero.

Comment: I updated my original post above with the json I'm using for insert that's still throwing an error.

Comment: samol518, regarding your updated answer... this should not be the case. You should be able to duplicate it with the steps I've updated in my post.